# How to get only the values in an object which are defined by an array of keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, find

I have a simple object with several keys and values:

```
var obj = {SKA: 267, SKB: 30, SKC: 273, SKD: 900, SKE: 27, SKF: 3}
```

I also have a array with some keys:

```
var keysArray = ["SKB", "SKF"]
```

I know that I can get all values by using `Object.values(obj)`. However I only need the values of the keys which are defined in the `keysArray`. So, is there a simple way to get only the values of these keys and save them in a new array?

I need the following result:

```
var resultArray = [30, 3]
```

Many thanks.

Comment: The keys are strings?

Comment: yes, they are strings and your solution below works perfect, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 keysArray.map(key => obj[key])
```

Comment: if there is a key which is not in `obj`, it'll map to undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
var resultArray =[];

keysArray.forEach(function(key){
    if(obj[key]){
        resultArray.push(obj[key]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use loop, like `forEach` on the `keysArray` instead of `map` on `keysArray`. The reason for this is because `map` do not work for this:

```js
var obj = {SKA: 267, SKB: 30, SKC: 273, SKD: 900, SKE: 27, SKF: 3};
var keysArray = ["SKB", "SKF"];
var resultArray = [];

keysArray.forEach((key)=>{
  resultArray.push(obj[key]);
});
console.log(resultArray);
```

Here is why `map` do not fit with what you have asked:

```js
var obj = {"SKA": 267, "SKB": 30, "SKC": 273, "SKD": 900, "SKE": 27, "SKF": 3};
var keysArray = ["SKB", "SKF"];

keysArray.map(key => obj[key]);
console.log(keysArray);
```